# Delete or close my question (MikTeX can’t find xstring)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I asked [MikTeX can’t find xstring](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80478/4918), because I wasn’t sure what the problem is and although I googled `miktex xstring` a didn’t found anything especially not the bug report that Ulrike linked in her comment. Now I wonder if my question should be closed (as too localized) or even deleted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be handled the same way as other questions, where it turned out, that the actual problem is caused by a bug: As far as I can tell, they are all closed as “Too localized”.

Deleting is in my eyes a bad idea. Now other people observing the same behaviour should find your question, what would not work, if it were deleted.

Comment: Thanks :-) I voted to close it …